# How to reorder barchart last two bars (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

[image]

I have this graph and I want to keep the descending order but fix the var Q7_1_66 and Q7_1_99 at the bottom.
I have no ideia how. Some advice?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: base=20
tituloQ7_1<-titulo[titulo$Var=="Q7.1", "Titulo"]
Q7.1<-freq[freq$esc=="Entrevista_final|1|ii|1|Q7_1",c("var","mod","PERCENT")]
Q7_1<-Q7.1[Q7.1$mod=="1",c("var","mod","PERCENT")]
ggplot(Q7_1, aes(x=reorder(var, +PERCENT), y=PERCENT))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width =.6, fill="red3")+
  geom_text(aes(label=sprintf(PERCENT,fmt="%1.0f")), vjust=0.4, hjust=-0.2)+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(caption = (paste("n= ", base)),
       x=NULL,
       y=NULL)+
  guides(x="none")+
  coord_flip()